# how to place server action listeners in a vuejs project?

Tags: vue.js, sockets, server, socket.io, chat

I am trying to make a simple chat app using vuejs and socketio.
I would like to broadcast a message from one user to all the others.
I have the following code on the server side to do that:

```
io.on('connection', socket => {
    socket.on('send-message', message => {
        console.log('message sent: ' + message)
        socket.broadcast.emit('receive-message', message)
    })
})
```

On the client side, I am listening to that action in this method:

```
this.socket.on('receive-message', message => {
        this.createMessageHtmlElement(message)
      })
```

I am having a hard time knowing where to place that method. putting in mounted() or created() will make it get called over and over again. I only want to call it when the server actually sends a message.

What is the correct way to place server action listeners in a vuejs project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> putting in mounted() or created() will make it get called over and
> over again.

`this.socket.on` is a "socket version" of `document.addEventListener` ([docs](https://socket.io/docs/v4/client-api/#socketoneventname-callback)) so, you will set a function (callback) that will be executed when a certain event occurs (`receive-message` in your case).  Depending on what `createMessageHtmlElement` actually does, you can put `this.socket.on` in either `created()` or `mounted()`.
Assuming you have a simple app, probably the best place to do that is `App.vue` since the listener is going to be registered when the `App.vue` is registered ([Vue lifecycle](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/lifecycle.html#lifecycle-diagram))